# Why is Cypress not running my plugin file?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my plugin/index.js I have written a task to clear one of my database tables:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */

    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('../../../db/db.sqlite3', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log('Connected to the database.');
    });
    
    
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
    
      on('task', {
        clearInvoices() {
    
    
    
          db.run(`DELETE FROM my_table`, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              return console.error(err.message);
            }
            console.log(`Row(s) deleted ${this.changes}`);
          });
    
          return null
        }
      })
    }
```

And I need the table to be cleared in the BeforeEach hook:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    cy.fixture('login.json').then((data) => {
        this.login_details = data
    }).then(function () {
        cy.login(this.login_details.username, this.login_details.password)
        cy.fixture('new_sale.json').then((data) => {
            this.new_sale_data = data
        })
    })
    cy.task('clearInvoices')
})
```

clearInvoices isn't being run.. is there some sort of configuration I need to do in order for Cypress to run this task?

Comment: Add some log to verify that plugins file is being processed on startup. The default location for plugins file is `cypress/plugins/index.js` and not `plugin/index.js`

Answer (score -1):

You may need to `return config` as can be seen here
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/plugins/index.ts#L41
in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/)